# How to match all paths that ends with nodes with common properties in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to match all paths from one given node.

```
         -->(c: {name:"*Tom*"})
        /
(a)-->(b)-->(d: {name:"*Tom*"})
        \           
         -->(e: {name:"*Tom*"})
```

These paths have specified structure that:
- the name of all children of the second-last node (b) should contain "Tom" substring.

How to write correct Cypher?

Comment: so basically, the very last node should contain "Tom"? What cypher have you already tried?

Comment: Yes, all last nodes should contain "Tom". Tried, but b is not a list. `match (:Person {name:"Start"})-[:FRIEND*]->(b:Person) where all(x in b where x.name=~'.*Tom.*')`

Comment: Why do you use variable length paths (`*`) in the first relationship?

Comment: because the path may contain 2 to more jumps. consider (a)->(a1)->(b)->... in the example graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's recreate the dataset:

```
CREATE
  (a:Person {name: 'Start'}),
  (b:Person),
  (c:Person {name: 'Tommy Lee Jones'}),
  (d:Person {name: 'Tom Hanks'}),
  (e:Person {name: 'Tom the Cat'}),
  (a)-[:FRIEND]->(b),
  (b)-[:FRIEND]->(c),
  (b)-[:FRIEND]->(d),
  (b)-[:FRIEND]->(e)
```

As you said in the comment, `all` requires a list. To get a list, you should use the [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function on the neighbours of `b`:

```
MATCH (:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(b:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(bn:Person)
WITH b, collect(bn) AS bns
WHERE all(bn in bns where bn.name =~ '.*Tom.*')
RETURN b, bns
```

We call `b`'s neighbours as `bn` and collect them to a `bns` list.

Comment: Really useful collect(x). Thank you very much